# How to change nodejs directory?

Tags: node.js, centos, yum

I have updated `nodejs` using `yum` on `Centos` OS, but programs still calling the old `nodejs` install in somewhere else.
How can I change the directory for `nodejs` and use the updated one?

```bash
(base) user@~:$ node -v
v0.10.24

(base) user@~:$ which node
/software/node/bin/node

(base) user@~:$ /usr/bin/node -v
v10.24.1
```

Comment: Fix your path?  Uninstall the old one?

Comment: Put the new node earlier in the system's PATH than the old node or remove the old node from PATH (and the system, if not needed anymore). Or if you need both versions, I recommend [Node Version Manager](https://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/using-a-node-version-manager.html) `nvm`.